PHPUnit 'Error : Class "path\to\class\classToTest" not found'
I'm trying to write some unit tests. However no matter what I do I keep getting this error:

Error : Class "path\to\class\classToTest" not found

The test I'm trying to run has a simple structure:
<?php
namespace tests\unit;

use path\to\class\classToTest;
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class className extends TestCase
{
  public function testname()
  {
    $classToTest = new classToTest;
    $result = $classToTest->test();
    $this->assertTrue($result);
  }
}

The classToTest looks like this:
<?php
namespace path\to\class;

class classToTest
{
  public function test()
  {
    return true;
  }
}

The autoload of the composer.json looks like this:
"autoload":
{
  "psr-4":
  {
    "FolderClassIsIn\\": "folderClassIsIn/"
  }
}


Check whether your composer.json file is configured to autoload the classes in the path/to/class namespace.

@Subha I have it added to the autoload in the composer.json in the following way: "FolderClassIsIn\": "folderClassIsIn/"
I'm not 100% sure it's the correct way but i legit have no idea what else it could be.

It would be better for me to understand if you edit your question and share only the autoload section of the composer.json file.

@Subha updated the question.

"path\\to\\class\\": "path/to/class" --add this after the existing one and  then check. On the right hand side provide the full path of the folder.As I dont know your folder structure I am not sure about it.

@Subha sadly this hasn't changed anything. I still get the same error when running the test.

Check the folder structure and naming convention issue since folder name is case-sensitive.

The issue was with case sensitivity.
Even when the folders were all lowercase, when using namespaces the first letter had to be uppercase.

Common with PSR-* based autoloaders. It is a little documented autoload design decision in the early phase of the PSR project (around 0.9): It's compatible with anything PSR which is basically all PHP frameworks (because that's what it defines), but not with the standard PHP SPL autoloading which does case-folding of the filenames to lowercase. Add autoload checks to your project and run them early. Example of a hybrid PSR-0 autoloader leaned onto SPL semantics and Basic autoload and namespace in php.
